# How to add email field in contactstruct

Tags: android

I have a problem while adding email field in contactstruct. I am developing a apps in which edittext values are converted into vcf file and stores it in a sd card. So kindly mentor me how to add email in the field

```
contact1.name = Name.getText().toString();
contact1.company = Company.getText().toString();                    

contact1.title=Email.getText().toString();      
contact1.addPhone(Contacts.Phones.TYPE_MOBILE, ContacttNo.getText().toString(), null, true);
// create vCard representation                  
String vcardString = composer.createVCard(contact1, VCardComposer.VERSION_VCARD30_INT);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this library https://code.google.com/p/android-vcard/. There u will find the samples

Answer (score 0):

For the raw contact information it's `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email`

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html